# Frequency changing element in an FM transmitter

Tags: rf, frequency-modulation

In a simple FM transmitter such as this [image]

What element does the frequency modulation? I don't mean the oscillation itself, since it's clearly created by tuned tank circuit, but the modulation. There is no VCO or anything so what exactly changes the frequency of the wave?

Comment: Other than Q1 and C2?

Comment: I guess that's the question. If it were using let's say a varicap I'd understand the mechanism, but here it basically regulates how much current is going through the C2 if I understand it correctly, so how exactly does the frequency change?

Comment: V_CE changes, which changes that tank.

Comment: Basically C2 becomes part of the tank circuit?

Comment: Q1 and C2 are a second tank.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. I'm guessing Q1 and C2 is RC tank?

Comment: Yes, and the audio input changes R.

Comment: The question asked here is "explain this (fairly complex) circuit I found on the internet", and without you understanding most of that circuit and asking a specific question, such questions are *always* too broad. Compare: **[How to deal with “Explain/Fix this Circuit I found somewhere (and don't really understand)” kind of questions?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/how-to-deal-with-explain-fix-this-circuit-i-found-somewhere-and-dont-really-u)**

Comment: How come the question is broad? The member above explained the phenomenon (even if not completely) in quite simple terms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple FM transmitter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104553/simple-fm-transmitter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mic outputs some audio ac voltage which is as an addition on the supplied dc between its terminals. That ac varies directly the operating point of the transistor. The internal junction capasitances of the transistor vary and that affects directly to the oscillating frequency.

Addendum: For example think the capasitance between c and b. Its changes affect through other capasitors on what is in parallel with the coil.

The fm deviation is difficult to pretend. For this reason fm is often realized by having a varactor in the resonant circuit an applying the audio ac to it.

Comment: So if we consider the RLC tank circuit, by applying voltage to the base we not only change the R component but C component as well?

Comment: The answer is augmented due the comment.